# How do I punctuate a list a questions in one sentence in a workbook context?

Tags: punctuation

Do I use question marks in place of commas in a sentence that includes several questions? If so, do I follow the question marks with a lower case letter as given in the examples below.

Examples:

> Have you felt compelled to be more generous? to stop holding on to things you don't use? to share with others who are in need?
>
> How was the work production today? why? and when do you think that will change?

Comment: I'm old-fashioned and follow Fowler's Modern English Usage. He approved of lower case after intermediate question marks. The only way to settle questions of punctuation is to choose a style guide such as The Times, or Guardian or Random House.